# Why cannot 'meaning' substitute 'semantic'?

Tags: terminology

Why can't (the Noun Adjunct) 'meaning' substitute (the Adjective)  'semantic' (I bolded) in the examples below?

<sub>Source: Paul Elbourne, *Meaning: A Slim Guide to Semantics* (1 ed. 2011).</sub>

> [ [p. 33](https://books.google.com/books?id=IcNEH279CsgC&lpg=PA40&ots=npJ94Xanvt&dq=semantics%20slim%20guide%20%22semantic%22&pg=PA33#v=onepage&q=semantic&f=false) : ]   In this chapter I will discuss some **semantic** properties that words 
>   are traditionally supposed to have. I will concentrate on synonymy, 
>   ambiguity, and vagueness.
>
> [ [p. 40](https://books.google.com/books?id=IcNEH279CsgC&lpg=PA40&ots=npJ94Xanvt&dq=semantics%20slim%20guide%20%22semantic%22&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q=semantic&f=false) : ] Faster processing caused by **semantic** similarity is called ***semantic*** priming.
>
> [ [p. 117](https://books.google.com/books?id=IcNEH279CsgC&lpg=PA40&ots=npJ94Xanvt&dq=semantics%20slim%20guide%20%22semantic%22&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q=semantic&f=false) : ]  Anaphora is the **semantic** 
>   dependency between pronouns and Other phrases illustrated in (2) 
>   and (7): the pronouns in these cases seem to be dependent on preceding quantifier phrases in some way for their **semantic** functioning.
>
> [ [p. 126](https://books.google.com/books?id=IcNEH279CsgC&lpg=PA40&ots=npJ94Xanvt&dq=semantics%20slim%20guide%20%22semantic%22&pg=PA126#v=onepage&q=semantic&f=false) : ] So now we come to the claim 
>   about the proposition expressed that involves covert indexicals: it 
>   is that the proposition expressed is always the result of assigning 
>   referents or other **semantic** values to the words in a syntactic tree and 
>   then combining those **semantic** values by means of compositional 
>   rules.

Comment: Do you have evidence that "semantic" *can't* be replaced with "meaning" and still refer to the same facts? I assume you're not asking about the style question, which would be off topic.

Comment: Because meaning is a noun and semantic is an adjective.

Comment: @curiousdannii I meant, in my first sentence, that 'meaning' can be a Noun Adjunct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **meaning** is a dangerous term. There has been too much debate, during the XX century, about the "meaning of meaning", i.e. about the problem of defining the essence of the linguistic meaning as a phenomenon. A widely shared solution has never been reached in such respect. Therefore, authors might prefer to avoid such term at all.

Moreover, in the contemporary usage **semantics** refers to a network of selectional properties that a lexeme can have, rather than to a flat meaning. The latter can be easily ignored in a structural — grammatical, morphological or syntactic — analysis of the language. For example, we are usually not interested in the concrete meaning of the verbs, since doing grammar means making generalizations over a set of different but analogous elements. We are interested, instead, in their argumental structure, subcategorization etc., i.e. whether a verb is (di)transitive or intransitive, whether it imposes some semantic features on its arguments (like when we say that the verb *assassinate* must have a [+human] direct object while the verb *elapse* cannot have a [+human] subject), or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Because *meaning* refers to a particular or specific case or example, something practical, whilest *semantic* or *semantics* refer to an abstract theory of language in general, to metanarration.